# GWT App through tomcat on Intellij-Idea 10

Tags: gwt, tomcat, intellij-idea

Sounds simple, but I'm having lots of issues.

I want to run a GWT project in a tomcat on Intellij-idea 10.

Does anyone know how to set up the run config?

Regards,
Charles.

Answer (score 5):

You can use '-noserver' option to start Dev Mode under Tomcat. Edit your GWT run configuration by adding '-noserver -port 8080' to 'Dev Mode parameters' field, then run the Tomcat configuration and after that run the GWT configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This all implies that this is a development run, i.e. for local testing/debugging purposes. This is not deployment to production servers. I also assume you have GWT and Web facets defined for this project.

1. If you need GWT debugging, then you must run as GWT run configuration: here you can only choose a Default server (Jetty that comes with GWT) or an AppEngine Development server (if installed).
2. If you *must* run under Tomcat, then:

   a. Add a Tomcat server under Settings - App Servers.

   b. Create an Artifact - WAR exploded (under project settings). Add all items in right pane to the left pane.

   b. Create a Tomcat run configuration with this Artifact.

Comment: Unfortunately i MUST run it under tomcat in dev mode. (dont ask!!!) Thanks for this, it works, but every time you do a 'make' the whole GWT compilation happens, which takes ages, do you know any way round this?

Answer (score -1):

You first run gwt compiler for compile gwt module, then compiler creates to your hosted .js and .html files. And you can run tomcat as usual but tomcat does not compiles your gwt modules. 
I suggest you t use ant to compile gwt modules.